# Query, check where values are the same

Tags: sql

I have this query here:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT formas.*, 
                  SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
                  SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
                  SMS_SERVISI.time_added
             FROM formas 
        LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON 'formas.id_f' = 'SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET' 
            WHERE (SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET !='' or SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET is not null)
              AND formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='K' 
         ORDER BY formas.id DESC;";
```

My problem is in the ON `'formas.id_f' = 'SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET'`

It won't work, this values are both varchar type and it would be i.e 
ON K3=K3
But it won't work...
Maybe it's not used the operator = to see if two fields are the same.
Thanks

Comment: An extra **Information**. Replace **`WHERE (SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET !='' or SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET is not null)`** with **`WHERE ISNULL(SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,'')<>''`**

Comment: it gives me an error if i do it like you said..

Comment: now the query is correct but still, it's not making equal idticket and formas.id...

Comment: if you remove SMS_SERVISI from the query do you get any results? ie `$strSQL = "SELECT formas.*, '' as IDTICKET, '' as MBYLLUR, '' as time_added FROM formas  WHERE formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='K' ORDER BY formas.id DESC;";` you're left joining that table so removing it shouldn't make a difference for testing

Comment: **[ISNULL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0831/2)**

Comment: Huh, i'm going crazy why isn't this working on my program though...

Comment: Because you have some different data there. And Join isn't producing any Result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the clause

```
ON formas.id_f = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
```

Otherwise you're just doing a string comparison of the string `formas.id_f` and `SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET` and not the values that the fields hold...

Comment: i did that but still didn't work...

Comment: @AlAl it shouldn't have the single quotes

Comment: @AlAl it looks to me that this is a PHP related question as well - if you run the query directly against the database (outside of your application code) do you get results?

Comment: It works if  i use the same query but i use it to compare two int types it works, but if i put two varchat types it won't the formas.id holds values like : K120 while the IDTICKET holds values like A1293

Comment: @AlAl so formas.id holds values like : K120 and IDTICKET holds values like A1293; but is it ever the case that both formas.id and IDTICKET hold values like K120 or A1293 ie the same value?

Comment: Yes, i mean, they can hold both K12 for example

Answer (score 1):

try to change it to (remove " ' " single quotes symbol)

```
ON formas.id_f = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
```

Comment: Hmm no, still won't work..

Comment: @AlAl what is the error?

Comment: There's noe rror, it just won't print what it should, even if i try with "" or without them..

Comment: @AlAl can you post the tables with data and result, you expect from your query?

Comment: So, if i use the same query but i use it to compare two int types it works, but if i put two varchat types it won't
the formas.id holds values like : K120 while the IDTICKET holds values like A1293

Comment: @AlAl It should work with both ints and varchars, but both of them must have the same type, or you should case one type to another. If formas.id has value K120 and IDTICKET has value K120 - they will be joined by it in your query. But if formas.id has value K120 and IDTICKET holds values A1293, so K120 != A1293 and your result will have 0 records

Comment: Yes voo, i understand, but there are values like K13 in formas.id_f and K13 in IDTICKET too so it should work,,

Comment: @AlAl can you make it on SQL Fiddler?

Comment: I'm making it here
i have an issue witht he query, i'm doing something wrong
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e8fc/3

Comment: remove the comma at the end of the field `SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET` and remove the single quotes from the join clause

Comment: Your **[Answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e8fc/14)**

Comment: So, both formas_id and IDTICKET are varchar types..

Comment: @AlAl remove , after SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, - see Luv fiddle, your query works